# What to do about duplicate question that has bounty?

Tags: discussion

What should I do if I found the answer already on AU for a question that has a bounty currently on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the questions touch on the same things, and the answer on the other question is an exact fix for the issue, then flag for a moderator.  We are able to close questions that have bounties on them and mark them as duplicates of other questions.

(This is also the same process for closing as a duplicate or offtopic, too, flag for moderator review/attention).